# Mount 1x2.5" hard drive and 1x3.5" hard drive in 1x5.25" bay?

Tags: hard-drive

Is it actually possible to mount 1x2.5" hard drive and 1x3.5" hard drive in 1x5.25" bay?

Comment: Both in the same bay?

Comment: they would fit (tightly), but i don't know that I've seen any adapters for that. closest I've seen was a 4x and a 6x 2.5" adapter for a single 5.25" bay.

Comment: @Shinrai: Yes, both in the same bay at the same time.

Comment: @Xantec: I have also seen those 4x2.5" in a single 5.25 bay.

Answer (score 2):

OK, now I've seen something new. Items you're looking for do exist, such as the [StarTech SATADOCK525](http://us.startech.com/product/SATADOCK525-525in-Bay-Mounted-25in-and-35in-SATA-Hard-Drive-Docking-Station). Cheers.

> The HDD dock accommodates both 2.5in and 3.5in SATA hard drives and can support one of each at the same time. Plus, when the 3.5in slot is not in use, two 2.5in drives can be inserted simultaneously.

Comment: @Jose if this is the answer to your question then you might consider accepting it

Answer (score 1):

I think it should just about fit (depending on how thick the HDDs are) - but you're going to need a custom bracket to do it - I've never seen anything like that for sale.